# Go type for conversion to *ptrdiff_t?

Tags: go, cgo

In my Go program where I'm invoking a C function I can successfully convert from `int` to `ptrdiff_t`. (Somewhat concerningly even `int8` will compile successfully even though the Go type is far too small for any modern architecture.) However `*int` to `*ptrdiff_t` yields a compiler error:  `cannot convert <varname> (type *int) to type *_Ctype_ptrdiff_t`. The only type that permits successful compilation is `int64`.  I realize I can declare my variable as (*)C.ptrdiff_t but I want to understand the appropriate corresponding Go type and the unexpected behavior of the Go compiler in this instance?

Answer (score 2):

A ptrdiff_t is an integer type of a particular size. When you convert another integer type to a ptrdiff_t, the compiler re-sizes the integer. In other words, it changes the memory representation of the old integer to match the new type. This new representation is then put in a different location in memory.

A pointer is a location in memory. Therefore, you can only convert to a type that points to the same memory layout. An int64 has the same size as a ptrdiff_t so the memory representation is the same and the pointer can be converted freely.

If you wish to convert an arbitrary integer type, you need to first change its in memory representation and give it a new location by assigning it to a variable and taking its pointer.

```
newtype := ptrdiff_t(oldInt)
pnewtype := &newtype
```

Comment: Aha, the piece I was missing was that an int8 will be expanded into the appropriate size. Presumably if I was compiling in an environment  where ptrdiff_t was 32 bits then using int64 would trigger a warning or error. Which leads me to believe that using *int64 as the Go equivalent to *ptrdiff_t is only applicable in 64-bit builds. Is there an architecture-agnostic Go type that will work? I tried uintptr because it's guaranteed to be sized to hold a pointer (and thus should be appropriate to hold the difference between pointers)  but Go did not allow the conversion.

Comment: @errcw, in Go, to convert a pointer to an instance of a concrete type to `uintptr` you have to first convert it to `unsafe.Pointer`, so this works: `x := X{}; var p uintptr = uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&x))`

Comment: Fair enough, but that still leaves me wondering what the correct architecture-agnostic Go type is that maps to *C.ptrdiff_t.